# Using One UIImageView that Changes Based on Button Pushed

Tags: ios5, uiimageview

This is a very basic question, but I cannot figure this out. I'm new to iOS/XCode. I've gone through a few tutorials that somewhat covered this (but a little more complex). I have an Android app that I'm trying to port over to iOS. I'm using storyboards for this app.

The basic premise is that the app contains 27 thumbnail/full images. For this question, we'll say the 27 pictures are split into 4 categories: cats, dogs, sharks, whales. Currently, I have the app launching with Navigation Controller w/ View that shows 4 Buttons with these categories. These push out to 4 separate view controllers each set up with buttons with the thumbnail as the image. I want to select the thumbnail and show a scene with the full image. I only want one full image view controller with a UIImageView in it that will display the full image of the thumbnail pressed. (Using table views may be easier, but I want to control the user interface and have more than just a rows of items to select.) Also, I'm not sure if this matters in the eventual set up, but from the full image scene I will want to add a play button that will play a local mp4 file (but that's for another day).

The image set will remain static so I was trying to incorporate NSArray with the full image name stored. I believe I have to add a file that is subclass of ViewController and incorporate code that will take on the full image file name based on the button pushed. This is where I'm stuck. In java for Android, I just had listeners on each button and used a case statement to set the full image variable and passed it to my full image class/xml.

Another option I think I remember seeing somewhere is I could use the title of each button and enter the full image name there. Then when the button is pressed, the title is passed to the full image view. I think this eliminates the need for an array (???).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: What is your question, fellow? Please be specific..

Comment: I want 20+ separate buttons to use the same full image View Controller.

Comment: You mean there are 20 image(buttons) thumbs, in one page, and on clicking that you want that to, navigate to another page in which you want to display same image you have tapped, in  full size. Is this it?

Comment: Kind of. 1st Page - 4 buttons (Cats, Dogs, Sharks, Whale). Each button will open a different page with thumbnails. These I have already built through storyboard. Here's my question: Each Animal page will have 4 thumbnails each. Instead of creating one scene per thumbnail, I want to create one page that all 16 thumbnails will use to display the full image. If the brown dog thumbnail is pressed, full image is displayed. User goes back and selects black dog, full image is displayed. Both using the same viewController with UIImageView.

Comment: Oh, okay, this is easy to manage, Okay, now I got u. What you need to do is to use 3, 2, or even one controller class(which will be bit complicated to manage, but we can go with that). But for convenience you use 3 controller class, one for your category page, one on which category's thumb shows and last where your full image will be displayed, is that what you want?. Now the last query, you have image at your, local end or you have server url to download that?

Comment: thanks for your help on this. All images will be stored locally within the app. No looking online or on the users phone. My main focus getting the one controller set up for the full image to be displayed. Am I headed in the right direction with using NSArray?

Comment: Yes sure. But Here I'll suggest you to use, `NSMutableDictionary` of `NSMutableArray`, in one dictionary, `categoryDictionary`, Add following four Array, CatsImgArray, DogsImgArray, SharksImgArray, WhaleImgArray, Now while clicking on any category move to second page, where, you show image thumb of that category, and here set thumb with `tag` (this tag will be the index value of your image in array), now on clicking on this image, move to fullImage display page, where you can get image you want, `like [[categoryDictionary valueForKey;@"CatsImgArray"] objectAtIndex: thisImageIndex];`

Comment: And as you said the title is passed to full image page, make reverse, use mutable array of dictionary. Here, you may use an array, with global scope, or you may just pass the reference. Of your array.

Comment: Thanks rptwsthi. I will be playing around with this this weekend. I think you've got me headed on the right track.